# Fetching a sum of intervals in JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, hsqldb, jooq

I am looking for a dialect-independent way to return the sum of interval durations between two TIMESTAMP fields, using a select like:

```
DSL.sum(DSL.timestampDiff(MY_TABLE.START, MY_TABLE.END))
```

In JOOQ, `sum(...)` returns a `Field<BigDecimal>`. This happens to work in HSQLDB, as it uses a millisecond representation for the INTERVAL. In PostgreSQL, however, this query crashes as there is no automatic conversion from the native INTERVAL type to BigDecimal possible.

I am now looking for a cross-platform way in JOOQ to convert the INTERVAL to (milli)seconds, so I can sum these numbers to a numeric value.

Any suggestions? (Or perhaps there is a more elegant way to solve this puzzle?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably a bug in jOOQ ([#5785](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5785)).

As a workaround, you can implement your own sum function like this:

```java
public static Field<BigDecimal> sumTimestampDiff(
    final Field<Timestamp> start, 
    final Field<Timestamp> end
) {
    return new CustomField<BigDecimal>("sum", SQLDataType.NUMERIC) {
        @Override
        public void accept(Context<?> ctx) {
            switch (ctx.family()) {
                case HSQLDB:
                    ctx.visit(sum(timestampDiff(start, end)));
                    break;
                case POSTGRES:
                    ctx.visit(sql("sum(1000 * extract('epoch' from ({0} - {1})))", 
                                  start, end));
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I'm using [the `extract()` expression from Evan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41619326/521799).

The above code snippet assumes you have this static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

[More info about `CustomField` here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/).

Comment: I wouldn't likely do that in any of my code. I would store the the intervals, as intervals, and want an interval back. Or do my operations in the DB where intervals are significant and handled properly.  But, I have no idea how he's using jooq. Upvoted for incorporating it in his language though.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I know what you mean, but if you want to be database vendor agnostic, sometimes, you have to work around limitations / incompatibilities.

Comment: I was indeed looking for the JOOQ way to handle intervals in a platform-neutral way. For me this includes both the inline (SQL) conversion to a quantity of defined time units, but also fetching the result of an interval query as some interval type (like a Java 8 Duration). @LukasEder: Thank you for registering this issue as a bug.

Comment: PS: The proposed solution actually returns milliseconds in HSQLDB, and seconds from PostgreSQL. (Also note that the example code should read `SQLDataType.NUMERIC`, and there is a `;` missing after the `return` clause.) - But I love the quick response and clear solution; you saved my day!

Comment: @Timo: OK, fixed the ms vs seconds issue and syntax errors. Unfortunately, `java.time.Duration` is not a well suited type as it does not correspond to any SQL interval type at all, it just internally stores seconds (e.g. a minute doesn't always have 60 seconds!). `timestampDiff()` does return a platform independent interval type (`DayToSecond`), but `sum()` currently doesn't work with it.

Comment: isn't there a way to convert the  Field<DayToSecond> to Field<BigDecimal>  using an inline lambda?

Comment: @Nikos: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Would you mind asking a new question?

Answer (score 1):

From [the lists](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20060912150408.GA9148%40a-kretschmer.de)

```
select extract ('epoch' from '5 days 5 hours'::interval);
```

Comment: Although this is the correct (and commonly known) PostgreSQL solution, this is no JOOQ syntax.